# Access ViewModel in ObservableCollection by Underlying Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an ObservableCollection that I bind to a ListView. The ObservableCollection contains `ClientViewModel`s which are ViewModel wrappers for my `Client` model that contain UI-only properties.

The problem I am having, is let's say a Client connects/disconnects and an event is raised. If I want to update or remove the ClientViewModel from the ObservableCollection, I'd have to do some sort of LINQ hackery to search each ViewModel in the ObservableCollection, and then check if the Client inside the ClientViewModel is equal to the Client that connects/disconnected, and then modify the ViewModel.

Is there a more efficient way? Like having some sort of ObservableDictionary that can be accessed O(1)?

```
public ObservableCollection<ClientViewModel> ClientViewModels { get; } = new();

public void OnClientConnected(object sender, Client e)
{
    ClientViewModels[...]?
}
```

```
public class ClientViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Client Client { get; }

    private bool _online;
    public bool Online
    {
        get { return this._online; }
        set
        {
            this._online = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Online));
        }
    }

    public ClientViewModel(Client client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice you used `ObservableDictionary` and `ObservableCollection` in the description, and the code shows a `ObservableCollection`, a little confusing which you have and what you want.
On another note, does it have to be event driven? For something like this I usually like to run things on a timer, and update the entire list on some interval (maybe every 500ms).

Comment: @GingerNinja Corrected typo, thank you. And maybe I could try making it on a timer.

Comment: Not sure if the "online" thing is just an example to show your problem, or is the actual problem. But I would think that the status of someone being online could be delayed by a second or so. As doing these things with WPF events can sometimes be buggy when trying to update the innards of a list. So i prefer the explicit update which is more predictable. I could write an example for a solution if you want.

Comment: @GingerNinja The problem is just correlating the Client to the ClientViewModel in an efficient way. The online property is an example of something I'd like to update.

Comment: I think you will need to find or create a collection which implements INotifyCollectionChanged and IDictionary and can be accessed by index (index is required to notify removale of item).

Comment: But such collection still could need iteration of items internally to find the index.